# Detect a power failure on a PC using C programming

Tags: c, linux

I want to detect a power failure on a PC using C programming, there are few functions for CTRL_LOG_OFF , CTRL_SHUTDOWN etc in wincon.h .. how to handle unexpected power failure using c programming?

Comment: If your PC has no backup power supply (laptop or UPS), your program will fail anyway. For the other two your OS should provide proper means to report power state changes (power fail/low bat/shutdown).

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Before it fails, can I log the error in a text file indicating during which function execution it failed and what's the status of the function ( pass/ fail)?  Do we have any inbuilt function in c header or can we use signals in C ?

Comment: I don't understand why you think if the power goes out your computer can still do anything at anytime. There is not some sort of broadcasted event that says hey the power is going to go out in 5 seconds so clean up your program while you can. If there is a power failure then the computer cannot run.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to recover from an unexpected power failure is to regularly safe state data so either your program can a) just restart when the system is operational again, or b) can recover when the system is operational again.

When a power failure occurrs, the system just stops. Sometimes, hard disks manage to flush their internal cache buffers so the filesystem is consistent. But in general, there is insufficient power left for the system to "shutdown" or even to let your program know the power went off. And even, when it could tell *your* program, and can tell all the other 100 programs running on you system, there won't be enough power to let these do any action to be able to recover later. At best the system could dump memory and state to the hibernate file, but even for that there won't be enough power.

However, if you system is a laptop with battery, Windows will tell tour program it changed power status. The program receives the WM_POWERBROADCAST message for this. Then check the wParam parameter for the type of change. See Windows documentation for this message.

Answer (score 0):

When a computer looses power, the CPU (along with all other system peripherals) will also loose power and fail to continue executing instructions.  Hence, C (or any other language) code cannot be relied upon to **catch** such a catastrophic event, let alone take any action as the event occurs.

A common method is to note the status of a program in a file.  For example, when the program initializes, it could write a "running" status to the file. When the program terminates, it would write a "terminated" status to the file.  This would also allow the program to check the file status prior to initialization to see if the program terminated normally previously.

***Update:***

> What does SIGPWR do in Linux?

The SIGPWR signal indicates a change in the system's power status.

For example, a SIGPWR signal might issued by a processes associated with an "uninterruptible power supply" (UPS) that supplies power to the Linux system. The same (UPS) process writes status information to the file: 
`/var/run/powerstatus` (or the now deprecated, `/etc/powerstatus`).  The one letter value of this file will indicate the state of the system's power.  States include:

- 'F' Failing power. UPS is providing emergency power from its battery backup due to an external (or building) power failure.
- 'L' Low power. UPS is providing emergency power from its battery backup due to an external (or building) power failure.  However the UPS battery backup is critical low.  The system should shut-down immediately (within the next two minutes).
- 'O' Power OK. External (or building) power has been restored.

Other examples of SIGPWR might be associated with a system that has multiple (backup/redundant) power supplies, or a laptop that has its own battery power supply.

Comment: Thanks a lot . This is very helpful. I can maintain a log file which indicates the pass/ failure of function execution. But your explanation made me understand concept very clear. But I have  one query, what does sigpwr does in Linux?